# VB - Deploying a reference file

Tags: vb.net, deployment, reference

I am a bit of a novice to writing code so my apologies if this sounds a bit school boy ish,
I have created an Addin for a software I use at work, Autodesk Inventor, I am having an issue deploying the files to the correct location.

I have created the addin, all I need to do is put a dll file and a .Addin file into the correct location.

I thought I could do this by creating a new VB project in VS2010 and if I added the 2 files as references I could then write something that when the exe file is run it put the files in the correct location,

Is this Possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a Windows Installer deployment, then read [Windows Installer Deployment Walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/206sadcd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

If you want to do a ClickOnce deployment, then read [ClickOnce Deployment in .NET Framework 2.0](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c19523/ClickOnce-Deployment-in-NET-Framework-20.htm)